# Is there a convenient way to format a human readable byte size string in Freemarker?

Tags: string, numbers, format, freemarker, funnelback

There are plenty of answers to this question for Java  ([How to convert byte size into human readable format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758606/how-to-convert-byte-size-into-human-readable-format-in-java/3758880#3758880), and [Format file size as MB, GB etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263892/format-file-size-as-mb-gb-etc)) and [even for Groovy/Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797566/making-model-name-human-readable-in-groovy-grails), not to mention [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510434/format-bytes-to-kilobytes-megabytes-gigabytes), but is there a built-in or convenient way to do this in FreeMarker?

For clarity, I'm after the generic SI method in common parlance, rather than Binary powers of 2. E.g.

```
      1 ➤ 1B
    123 ➤ 123B
   1000 ➤ 1KB
   1728 ➤ 1.7KB
7077888 ➤ 7.1MB
```

And so on.

Given that FreeMarker doesn't appear to have a logarithm function, is there a way to do this in pure FreeMarker, or is my only option to create a Template Method with Java.

Comment: OK. Seems that if you're using Funnelback (as I am), there is a provided function called `filesize()` that achieves the desired result.

Comment: FreeMarker itself doesn't define `filesize()`. Something else puts it there in your environment.

Comment: @ddekany Yes. I know. [Funnelback](http://funelback.com) is what is putting it there.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is interested, I had a crack at coding up something myself using string manipulation. I wouldn't recommend doing something like this if you can avoid it, but if you're stuck, it might help:

```
<#--
 # Format Number of Bytes in SI Units
 # -->
<#function si num>
  <#assign order     = num?round?c?length />
  <#assign thousands = ((order - 1) / 3)?floor />
  <#if (thousands < 0)><#assign thousands = 0 /></#if>
  <#assign siMap = [ {"factor": 1, "unit": ""}, {"factor": 1000, "unit": "K"}, {"factor": 1000000, "unit": "M"}, {"factor": 1000000000, "unit":"G"}, {"factor": 1000000000000, "unit": "T"} ]/>
  <#assign siStr = (num / (siMap[thousands].factor))?string("0.#") + siMap[thousands].unit />
  <#return siStr />
</#function>
```

Comment: (Unrelated, but you don't need `()`-s after `#if` in FreeMarker. They do nothing.)

Comment: @ddekany You are right. Unless, of course, you are doing a "greater than" comparison. For example `<#if (num > 3)>` [as described in the Freemarker docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html#ref.directive.if). Personally, I like to keep the brackets in there so I don't forget them when I do write a greater-than comparison.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such functionality built in. BTW, that should be just a `number_format` pattern, but `DecimalFormat` doesn't have pattern that does this, so FreeMarker doesn't have it either.